# Why isn't express setting json content type?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I've used express many times over the years, and don't recall having this issue. I must be doing something wrong, but can't seem to pinpoint what that is.

I'm simply trying to use `res.json` to respond with a JSON payload, and the correct json content type. When inspecting the response, using chrome dev tools, there is no content type header set at all.

Here's my route handler ...

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const payload = await teams.getById(req.params.id);
    return res.json(payload);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
});
```

With this code, I see the JSON payload, but there's no content type header set at all. Any clues? Any middle-ware needed for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just clear your cache in chrome and try again.

I see `304 not modified request`, so server will not send any message body from server.  It may be the reason that it is not showing response content type.

And you are right. res.json will automatically set json content type.

Comment: **app.disable('etag')**  will return 200 OK and disable 304 not modified request